# Raspberry Pi 3b with Ubuntu 20.04 rainbow boot screen error

Tags: boot, server, 20.04, raspberrypi

I have a Raspberry Pi 3b+ V1.2 2014. I would like to run the 20.04 server on this raspberry pi. When I load up a 8 gb memory card using the raspberry pi imager V1.6.1 and I try to boot I only see the rainbow screen. The green light flashes for about 2-3 seconds then stops. The red light is solid red. I understand that this means the binary is not compatible. Here is what I have tried:

1. When I place the the 8 gb memory card with Ubuntu 20.04 in my raspberry pi 3b+ I get a rainbow screen of death.
2. When I place the the same 8 gb memory card with Ubuntu 20.04 in my raspberry pi 4 it boots fine.
3. I have tried the card in 2 different raspberry pi 3b+ computers with the same result (rainbow screen)
4. Raspberry pi OS 32 bit loads and works fine.
5. I have tried multiple power supplies. The largest one I have is 10 watts.

Is there a version of the binary that is created to work on the raspberry pi 3b+? Am I doing something wrong? Has anyone gotten this version of OS to work on the raspberry pi 3b+? Any help you can provide is appreciated.